# Excel Array formula IF function order of operations/priority

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

**Context:** I'm working on creating a dynamic tool in Excel to append existing ID's from our donor database onto incoming recurring gifts that will be imported.

I'm using an Array formula with multiple criteria to try and match IDs from our database based on incoming data of dubious quality (due to custom user input).

---

**Sample Content:**

By request, here are headings with a sample row below. First from one sheet, and then from the next.

***WISE_TRANSACTIONS_2***

```
Date    Type     Transaction Amount     Description Payment Type    Payment Name    Account Code    Email   First Name  Name.1.2    Last Name   Address 1   Address 2   City    State   Zip Country

7/31/2018 23:27 Sponsorship  $48.00     Sponsorship for Beneficiary XX11    Debit / MasterCard  Peter K Tular IND-0019793   petetee@icloud.com  Peter K Tular 123 Fake St       Los Angeles     Ca. 90043   US
```

***GIFT_ID_1***

```
First Name  Name.1.2    Last Name   Gift Type   Nickname    Constituent ID  Gift ID Gift Amount Preferred Address Line 1    Preferred City  Preferred State Preferred ZIP   E-Mail Number   Fund ID


Peter    Tular    Recurring Gift        81435   9777445    $48.00   123 Fake St Los Angeles California  90043   petertee@me.com     Sponsorship
```

---

**Problem:** My formula seems to not prioritize the first IF statement in a series of nested IF statements. This first IF is based on their email since that's likely the most unique identifier available from the import.

## Sorry the copied formula text is grotesque because of my weird excel formatting. Let me know if you'd like this redone in some way from my end.

---

Full formula - doesn't give e-mail priority, but I think it should
[image]

```
{=INDEX(GIFT_ID_1[#All],
             MATCH(1,
                                 (GIFT_ID_1[[#All],[Gift Amount]]=WISE_TRANSACTIONS_2[@[Transaction Amount]])*
                                  IF((LEFT(GIFT_ID_1[[#All],[E-Mail Number]],6)=LEFT(WISE_TRANSACTIONS_2[@Email],6)),
                                       (LEFT(GIFT_ID_1[[#All],[E-Mail Number]],6)=LEFT(WISE_TRANSACTIONS_2[@Email],6)),
                                       (IF((GIFT_ID_1[[#All],[Last Name]]=WISE_TRANSACTIONS_2[@[Last Name]]),
                                              (GIFT_ID_1[[#All],[Last Name]]=WISE_TRANSACTIONS_2[@[Last Name]]),
                                              IF((LEFT(GIFT_ID_1[[#All],[First Name]],6)=LEFT(WISE_TRANSACTIONS_2[@[Last Name]],6)),
                                                    (LEFT(GIFT_ID_1[[#All],[First Name]],6)=LEFT(WISE_TRANSACTIONS_2[@[Last Name]],6)),
                                                    IF((LEFT(GIFT_ID_1[[#All],[First Name]],6)=LEFT(WISE_TRANSACTIONS_2[@[First Name]],6)),
                                                         (LEFT(GIFT_ID_1[[#All],[First Name]],6)=LEFT(WISE_TRANSACTIONS_2[@[First Name]],6)),
                                                         (GIFT_ID_1[[#All],[Nickname]]=WISE_TRANSACTIONS_2[@[First Name]]))))*
                                           (IF((LEFT(GIFT_ID_1[[#All],[Preferred Address Line 1]],6)=LEFT(WISE_TRANSACTIONS_2[@[Address 1]],6)),
                                                  (LEFT(GIFT_ID_1[[#All],[Preferred Address Line 1]],6)=LEFT(WISE_TRANSACTIONS_2[@[Address 1]],6)),
                                              IF((GIFT_ID_1[[#All],[Preferred ZIP]]=WISE_TRANSACTIONS_2[@Zip]),
                                                   (GIFT_ID_1[[#All],[Preferred ZIP]]=WISE_TRANSACTIONS_2[@Zip]),
                                                   (GIFT_ID_1[[#All],[Preferred City]]=WISE_TRANSACTIONS_2[@City])))))),
                                        0),6)}
```

---

Instead it's using something less ideal, and several steps further down the line, like first name.

If I strip out the entire IF section of the formula, the email match works perfectly.

Reduced formula:
[image]

```
{=INDEX(GIFT_ID_1[#All],
             MATCH(1,
                                 (GIFT_ID_1[[#All],[Gift Amount]]=WISE_TRANSACTIONS_2[@[Transaction Amount]])*
                                  (LEFT(GIFT_ID_1[[#All],[E-Mail Number]],5)=LEFT(WISE_TRANSACTIONS_2[@Email],5)),
                                        0),6)}
```

---

What am I missing here? This is about as deep as I've dived into Excel up to now, and my first post on here ever. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Welcome! Can you please edit your question to include your formulas as text, instead of posting formulas as an image? You're more likely to get answers if people are able to copy/paste your code so they can work on your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jan, good suggestion I hadn't realized. I made some edits to hopefully provide more helpful info. Let me know if you think I should do anything differently.

Comment: I'm realizing something. The formula is probably working through my array from the top down, right? The problematic part I'm finding is where it catches someone with the same first name, and city/zip, instead of the same email. This person it's finding is 300 rows higher than the person with the identical email. Basically it found an "okay" match before the exact one.

Answer (score 1):

It's not perfect yet, but I've got it working for the problem cases I was looking at.

I realized the Index Match was making it's way down the Array, simply seeing who the first entry was it came across that matched anything it needed to find.

Therefore even though I was searching using

> Michael Hernando,    $48.00,    477 Bowter Plant Dr,   Apex,    NC,    35779, 
>      hernandos@gmail.com

This (with a different last name and unrelated email)

> Michael Johnson,    $48.00,   555 Nebraska Ave,    Apex,    NC,    35779,    tomatoboy@aol.com

Was found before this

> Michael Hernando,    $48.00,    911 Maui Ct,   Maggie Valley,    NC,    35688, 
>      hernandos@gmail.com

Because I allowed a worst case scenario where only the Transaction Amount, First Name and Zip or City all matched.

---

## Basically, I needed to tighten up my requirements. A few changes I made:

1. E-mail now searches everything up to the @ symbol. Because there are a few e-mail row's in my array's e-mail column that are empty, I had to throw in IFERROR to deal with #N/A results.
2. I figured a matching street address for 8 characters is a good indicator, so I put that on par with e-mail.
3. Alternatively, some semblance of matching First, Last and location is the backup method.
4. I also made simplified use of IF conditions after realizing we're just trying to get 1's and 0's.

The formula I went with was this

```
{=INDEX(GIFT_ID_1[#All],
       MATCH(1,
            (GIFT_ID_1[[#All],[Gift Amount]]=WISE_TRANSACTIONS_2[@[Transaction Amount]])    *
            IF(IFERROR((LEFT(GIFT_ID_1[[#All],[E-Mail Number]],FIND("@",GIFT_ID_1[[#All],[E-Mail Number]])-1)=LEFT(WISE_TRANSACTIONS_2[@Email],FIND("@",WISE_TRANSACTIONS_2[@Email])-1)),0)    +
              (LEFT(GIFT_ID_1[[#All],[Preferred Address Line 1]],8)=LEFT(WISE_TRANSACTIONS_2[@[Address 1]],8))    +
              (IF(IF((GIFT_ID_1[[#All],[Last Name]]=WISE_TRANSACTIONS_2[@[Last Name]])    +                                                            
                     (LEFT(GIFT_ID_1[[#All],[First Name]],6)=LEFT(WISE_TRANSACTIONS_2[@[Last Name]],6))
                      >0,1,0)    *                                            
                  IF(((LEFT(GIFT_ID_1[[#All],[First Name]],6)=LEFT(WISE_TRANSACTIONS_2[@[First Name]],6))    +                                                       
                      (GIFT_ID_1[[#All],[Nickname]]=WISE_TRANSACTIONS_2[@[First Name]]))
                       >0,1,0)    *
                  IF(((LEFT(GIFT_ID_1[[#All],[Preferred Address Line 1]],6)=LEFT(WISE_TRANSACTIONS_2[@[Address 1]],6))    +
                      (GIFT_ID_1[[#All],[Preferred ZIP]]=WISE_TRANSACTIONS_2[@Zip])    +
                      (GIFT_ID_1[[#All],[Preferred City]]=WISE_TRANSACTIONS_2[@City]))
                       >0,1,0)
                  >0,1,0))
             >0,1,0),
             0),6)}
```